# ¿Como puedo pasar el valor de un input al boton con jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Estoy haciendo un proyecto propio pero me he quedado atorado en algo. Tengo un input con un boton llamado agregar, entonces tengo una funcion de autocomplete, me funciona todo. Por ejemplo si escribo "COC", aparece una lista con el registro que tengo en la bd que es COCACOLA, al dar click enesa opción si se pasa el valor de todo ese registroa a mi boton llamado agregar, pero mi problema es que si escribo completamente "COCACOLA" doy click al boton pues no me agrega nada ya que no tiene el valor del input.
Solo funciona si usa la función autocomplete. No se si me doy a entender. Me pueden ayudar por favor, muchas gracias.

Este es mi input con mi boton

```
<input type="text" list="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="">
 <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-agregar">AGREGAR</button>
```

Esta es mi funcion de autocomplete

```
$("#nombre").autocomplete({
  source:function(request, response){
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?=base_url() ?>index.php/Ventas/getproductos",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data:{ valor: request.term},
      success:function(data){
        response(data);
      }

    });
  },
  minLength:1,
  select:function(event, ui){
    data = ui.item.id_producto+ "*"+ ui.item.codigo+ "*"+ ui.item.label+ "*"+ ui.item.precio+ "*"+ ui.item.stock;
    $("#btn-agregar").val(data);
  },

});
```

Comment: Para recoger el valor escrito tienes que tomar el valor del input text, si además el valor de data se lo aportas a este input y no al botón, recogeras tanto el autocomplete como el valor escrito desde el input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El autocomplete se comporta al final como un select, si no hay un evento click sobre un elemento este no es seleccionado.

Puedes trampearlo (no es la mejor solución ya que no es el comportamiento normal) un poco y agregarlo automáticamente al botón cuando el listado del autocomplete sea 1 elemento, quedando el código algo así:

```
$("#nombre").autocomplete({
  source:function(request, response){
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?=base_url() ?>index.php/Ventas/getproductos",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data:{ valor: request.term},
      success:function(data){
        if(data.length==1) {
           element = data[0].id_producto+ "*"+ data[0].codigo+ "*"+ data[0].label+ "*"+ data[0].precio+ "*"+ data[0].stock;
    $("#btn-agregar").val(element);
        }
        response(data);
      }

    });
  },
  minLength:1,
  select:function(event, ui){
    data = ui.item.id_producto+ "*"+ ui.item.codigo+ "*"+ ui.item.label+ "*"+ ui.item.precio+ "*"+ ui.item.stock;
    $("#btn-agregar").val(data);
  },

});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió . Saludos cordiales.